# On iOS: User allows camera but the video element is blank & console error "Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError"

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mediadevices

Why do I get `Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError` even after the user allows the camera for the page?

I have a webpage that is requesting the camera and streaming it to a video element on the page.  It works on my laptop (chrome), but on iOS (safari & chrome), the video element is blank, and there's a console error saying

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

and the line number for the exception is on the line that plays the video `this.video.play()`. See below.

#### HTML

```
            <div class="camera" class.bind="cameraLoading ? 'hidden' : ''">
                <video id="camera-view" ref="video">Video stream not available.</video>
                <div id="button-div">
                    <button id="capture-button" ref="captureButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <canvas id="overlay-canvas" ref="overlayCanvas"></canvas>
            </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
        let constraints = {
            video: {
                width: {ideal: 2160},
                height: {ideal: 2160}
            }
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((stream) => {
                let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                let capabilities = videoTrack.getCapabilities();
                let ideal = Math.min(capabilities.width.max, capabilities.height.max)
                videoTrack.applyConstraints({video: {ideal: ideal}, width: {ideal: ideal}, aspectRatio: 1})
                this.video.srcObject = stream

                this.video.play()

                setInterval(() => {
                    this.cameraLoading = false
                }, 50)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`An error occurred:`, err)
            })
```

Interestingly, if I click the button to capture the picture.  It does capture the picture from the camera.  It's just that the video stream isn't getting to the video element.  Also, if I navigate to a different view and then come back to the camera view without ever reloading the page (it's a single-page app), the video element loads perfectly.  Also, and I'm not sure this is related, it sometimes loads the video element fullscreen.

Comment: Your post doesn't ask an actual question.  And the answer you submitted is requesting further input.  That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add **`playsinline`** to the video element.  I stumbled on this when I was trying to figure out why it sometimes loaded fullscreen, and I'm not entirely sure why it works.  I also added `preload="none"`, but I've tested them separately, and `playsinline` is solving the problem.

```
<video id="camera-view" ref="video" playsinline>Video stream not available.</video>
```